# How child of tabview can access elements of view which holds tabview?

Tags: android

I have a button and below i have tabview with several tabs.
Wherewer I choose a tab I want to listen clics for elements on main activity. For example how can I listen clicks for `imRefresh`?
If I set onitem click listener I recieve nullpointer exception

main activity,  which ititialise tabview

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); 

        // Android tab
        Intent intentAndroid = new Intent().setClass(this, Tab1Activity.class);
        TabSpec tabSpecAndroid = tabHost
          .newTabSpec("Test1")
          .setIndicator("Test1")
          .setContent(intentAndroid);

        // Apple tab
        Intent intentApple = new Intent().setClass(this, Tab2Activity.class);
        TabSpec tabSpecApple = tabHost
          .newTabSpec("Test2")
          .setIndicator("Test2")
          .setContent(intentApple);



        // add all tabs 
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpecAndroid);
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpecApple);


        //set Windows tab as default (zero based)
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
    }

}
```

layout of main activity

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/for_t"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imRefresh"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView3"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_refresh" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imSearch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="yarh.youtubenblog.MainActivity"
        tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

        <TabHost
            android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                </TabWidget>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                </FrameLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </TabHost>
    </FrameLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

one of tabs activity

```
public class Tab2Activity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ImageView refresh = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imRefresh);
        refresh.setOnClickListener(refreshV);
        TextView textview = new TextView(this);
        textview.setText("This is Apple tab");
        setContentView(textview);
    }
    private OnClickListener refreshV = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            GetAdds feed = new GetAdds();
            feed.execute();

        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't - period. Not even via hacking around with ViewParents and window hierarchies. Sorry. This is due to how TabActivity works: Each of its tabs is actually its own self-contained Activity, that gets kind of "transplanted" into the TabActivity via some magic on the Android Framework's side. Separate activities have absolutely no way (via Android APIs) of getting view information about each other.

What'd make your task a lot simpler, is to switch to Fragments. Your use case is one of the most common examples: check out http://android.codeandmagic.org/android-tabs-with-fragments/

Comment: Isnt there a simple hacking way(though breaking oo rules an using cross referencing)? Either get parent and use reflection or passing tab view as parameter to inherited children of tab view via method(cross ref)?

Comment: No, sorry. There is absolutely no way for one `Activity` to find out information about another - this is by design. Each activity draws into and only knows about its own `Window`. There's a central system service called the `Window Manager Service` that knows about all the different windows, but it's in a separate process from your Activity and is thus completely inaccessible even via Reflection. (This is the reason that implementing an entire-screen Screenshot function is impossible for individual apps - it must be done at the OS level, or with a helper library and root access.)

Comment: Thx. I still will try to poc it.